# python multiprocessing with while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am trying to experiment multiprocessing with while loop and opencv to check wether it can run. Now the problem is when I close the opencv, the while loop is still running. How do I also stop the while loop after I hit the "q" for opencv.

here is my code:

```
 def do():
 global x, ipVal
 if y == 1:
      sys.exit()
 else:
      while y == 0:
           #print(str(flag1))
           x = x + 1
           time.sleep(5)
           #print('sleeping')
           print(x)
           if x == 2:
                x = 0
           if y == 1:
                break

def doX():
 global ipVal, num_cont, x
 if x == 0:
         print('0')  
 if x == 1:
         print('1')       
 if x == 2:
         print('2')  
         
 video1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
 video1.set(3, 640)
 video1.set(4, 480)

 while video1.isOpened():
      __,cv2_im = video1.read()
      __,cv2_im2 = video1.read()
      diff = cv2.absdiff(cv2_im, cv2_im2)
      gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray1, (5,5), 0)
      _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 20,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
      dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
      contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
      for contour in contours:
           (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
     
           if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 900:
                continue
           else:
                cv2.rectangle(cv2_im, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.putText(cv2_im, "Status: {}".format('Movement'), (10,20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 
                     1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
                cv2.putText(cv2_im, "Number of contours = {}".format(len(contours)), (400, 35), 
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0,0,0), 1)
                num_cont = len(contour)
      
      
      frame_resized = rescale_frame(cv2_im, scale=.2)
      
      cv2.imshow('frame1',frame_resized)
      if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord("q"):       # press "q" key to exit loop
           break
 video1.release()
 y = 1
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 sys.exit()

def runInParallel(*fns):
 proc = []
 for fn in fns:
      p = Process(target=fn)
      p.start()
      proc.append(p)
 for p in proc:
      p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
 
 runInParallel(do,doX)
```

thanks for helping...I tried sys.exit() and I also placed a break.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [**keyboard**](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module for this, here is the example:

first, install it with:

```
pip install keyboard
```

now use it in your while loop like this:

```
while <Your Condition>:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        print("You pressed 'q'.")
        break
```